# Github Bad REST API Design

Tags: api, rest, github-api, urn

I was investigating Github's REST API and stumbled upon some weird URLs. Github has two main resources /user and /users, where /user reffers to the authenticated user and /users two any particular user.

Isnt this going against the definition of URNs? Mainly because of these two points:

1. There are two different identifiers that reference the same entity.
2. /user does not uniquely represent a resource, but gives different responses to everyone even against successful requests.

Answer (score 2):

> There are two different identifiers that reference the same entity.

That's completely valid - see [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1); it's perfectly normal to have many different *resources* with overlapping, or even equivalent, representations, and of course those representations may be produced using information from common entities.

There are trade offs, of course - the successful processing of unsafe requests by *this* resource won't invalidate cached responses for *that* resource; see [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

> /user does not uniquely represent a resource, but gives different responses to everyone even against successful requests.

This one is messier.

The TL;DR version is that in HTTP it is OK, because we have special rules for [caching responses to authenticated requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-3.2).

The longer version is that we already have a notion that a single resource might have multiple valid representations; that we can use either proactive or reactive [content negotiation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-3.4) to determine which representation to include in a response to a client, we have the [Vary](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.4) header to assist caches in understanding when a response can be re-used, and so on.

Should the XML document and the JSON document be two different resources? or two different representations of the same resource?  Should the English document and the French document be two different resources or two different representations of the same resource?

There are cases where the "different representations of the same resource" answers make sense, and therefore "gives different responses" isn't necessarily a down check.

Of course, Authorization isn't just content negotiation, in the way that Accept and Accept-Language are.  So we have special rules:

> there is no need to send the Authorization field name in Vary because reuse across users is constrained by the field definition -- [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.4)

---

In summary, it's certainly an *allowed* design.  Whether or not it is also a *good* design is going to depend, in part, on the collection of constraints that they needed to satisfy.

In a design review, I would reject the Github design in the absence of constraints that made it necessary - in my mind the document about Alice and the document about Bob are different resources (changing one doesn't change the other), and should clearly be labelled as such.

But if the designer was so constrained?  Ship it.